# Magento 2: Tax is calculate before applying discount

Tags: magento2, tax, discount, tax-calculation

We need to apply all the taxes after applying discount. But currently taxes are calculated before applying discount.

Screenshot: [image: Screenshot]As you can see how the tax are being calculate on 200 rather than on (200-14) = 186.

Here are tax settings in store - Configuration - Sales - Tax. (We have set it to calculate taxes after discount)

[image]

Discounts are being applied here programmatically following this [link](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-custom-discount-magento-2/)
because we have discounts based on the type of user logged in.

Any suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Under `System > Configuration > Tax > Calculation Settings` there are options for the order tax rules are applied, including Apply Customer Tax which can be either `Before Discount` or `After Discount`.

I'm assuming you currently have it set to Before Discount.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but in my case I set the tax amount programmatically.
So if you are into controlling and manipulating the tax in your module, follow these steps:

in your di.xml file add the following:

```
<preference for="Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax"/>
```

Add the following class override (in Vendor/Module/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Tax.php):

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Sales\Total\Quote;

use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory as CustomerAddressFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterfaceFactory as CustomerAddressRegionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address;
use Magento\Tax\Api\Data\TaxClassKeyInterface;
use Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation;

class Tax extends \Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax
{


    /**
    * Class constructor
    *
    * @param \Magento\Tax\Model\Config $taxConfig
    * @param \Magento\Tax\Api\TaxCalculationInterface $taxCalculationService
    * @param \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsInterfaceFactory $quoteDetailsDataObjectFactory
    * @param \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterfaceFactory $quoteDetailsItemDataObjectFactory
    * @param \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\TaxClassKeyInterfaceFactory $taxClassKeyDataObjectFactory
    * @param CustomerAddressFactory $customerAddressFactory
    * @param CustomerAddressRegionFactory $customerAddressRegionFactory
    * @param \Magento\Tax\Helper\Data $taxData
    */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Tax\Model\Config $taxConfig,
        \Magento\Tax\Api\TaxCalculationInterface $taxCalculationService,
        \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsInterfaceFactory $quoteDetailsDataObjectFactory,
        \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterfaceFactory $quoteDetailsItemDataObjectFactory,
        \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\TaxClassKeyInterfaceFactory $taxClassKeyDataObjectFactory,
        CustomerAddressFactory $customerAddressFactory,
        CustomerAddressRegionFactory $customerAddressRegionFactory,
        \Magento\Tax\Helper\Data $taxData
    ) {
        $this->setCode('tax');
        parent::__construct(
            $taxConfig,
            $taxCalculationService,
            $quoteDetailsDataObjectFactory,
            $quoteDetailsItemDataObjectFactory,
            $taxClassKeyDataObjectFactory,
            $customerAddressFactory,
            $customerAddressRegionFactory,
            $taxData
        );
    }

    /**
    * Custom Collect tax totals for quote address
    *
    * @param Quote $quote
    * @param ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
    * @param Address\Total $total
    * @return $this
    * @throws RemoteServiceUnavailableException
    */
    public function collect(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    ) {
        $total->setTotalAmount('tax', $set_your_tax_here);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('tax', $set_your_tax_here);
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have use your code but setTaxAmount is working but grand total count default magento tax not count custom ser tax amount.